# ddrescue cloning disk to disk. I cannot see anything in the new disk why?

Tags: ddrescue

I have a failing disk 1TB which does a bit of noise so I decide to use ddrescue to clone disk to disk the failing disk into a new WD 1TB.
I was expecting to see information in the new disk while cloning but i cannot see anything at all in it. It looks empty, in fact the cloning process stopped because i moved the old disk and I checked if there was something in the new disk and there was nothing!!! Why, what is happening? I continued the cloning again using the log file. The cloning goes very slow in 24 hours just 25GB has been cloned, but I cannot see anything in the new disk.

In the past when I created an image instead of cloning I could see how the image file was growing and even if I finished the creation of the image half way I could get info from the image.

What is happening? I dont want to be cloning a disk for 2 months a no info being stored in the new disk

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are cloning the disk to disk, you won't be able to "see" anything until you mount up the copy when it's all done.

I *think* you can go to another terminal and type `killall -USR1 dd` to have it report progress.

Comment: Aaron thanks so much for your answer..... but I am about to cry now        

I left the computer as a 3rd night running ddrescue doing a cloning disk to disk. 

When i got up this morning just the terminal was running but anything else.  the desktop and bars had dissapeared . So I closed the terminal and switched off the laptop manually 
I disconnected the 2 disks i had attached and I restarted the computer..... this is what I got 

error: attempt to read or write outside of partition 
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

what do I do now?

Comment: Sorry @toni but that is well beyond a comment thread. Good luck!